# Brute Force Approach for LCS and its Time Complexity

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, time-complexity, strings

I have read several Algorithm books where it is been told brute force approach of **Longest Common Subsequence** takes 2^n which is exponential time complexity. Whereas, I've noticed that while I am applying my brute force technique it's taking O(m*n) (from my personal observation). 
I would like to request you please read my approach clearly and visualize in mind and ask question for further clarification if needed.
My Approach is following:- Say we have two strings **s1** = "ECDGI" , **s2** = "ABCDEFGHIJ". 
Now what I am doing is I chose either one of the given strings. For say, s1. 
for i = 1 to n (**n** is the last index of s1), I am taking each value and comparing with the s2 in such a way that for a single character of s1 I am checking with all the characters of s2. Mathematically, ith value is checking through all jth value up to m (**m** is the last index of s2). Here, if I find any common character I just move to next character from both strings. Then just compute subsequence. I compute all the possible subsequence for each characters from s1 by running **n** loops. Finally, I compute the largest value.
From my understanding it's taking O(m*n) time complexity overall. 
So My Question is, **" Is my Time Complexity Calculation right ? "**

Trace :

i = 1, value = E, lcs = 3 [EGI]

i = 2, value = C, lcs = 4 [CDGI]

i = 3, value = D, lcs = 3 [DGI]

i = 4, value = G, lcs = 2 [GI]

i = 5, value = I, lcs = 1 [I]

Answer is = 4 (maximum lcs)

Comment: How will you move to next character for both strings if there is a match? The inner loop will be reset when you move for next character in outer loop. Once reset what if there is a match for the next character before the previous match. Your approach does not solve the problem, let alone the complexity.

Comment: Try two strings with duplicate characters and you will see your approach failing.

Comment: "I compute all the possible subsequence." That sounds like exponential operations. Anyway, the description of your algorithm is not clear enough. Can you add a link to your code  such as a page on https://replt.it? As @NavjotWaraich suggested, have you tried two strings such as "ababababa" and "acacacaca", whose longest subsequence should be "aaaaa"?

Comment: @NavjotWaraichI tried with duplicate strings also..

Comment: @Apass.Jack here's my code [link]https://ideone.com/SDiv0q (updated). I printout the the maximum number of longest sub-sequence. As it is just a Time Complexity checking, I tried to make the code simple with basic operations. I hope you will understand the code.

Comment: @ShahriarMim, please try "aba" and "acab".

Comment: @Apass.Jack ow that was a silly mistake. though it doesn't affect the time complexity. I made a mistake on doing increment. however, I updated the code. look at fork of above link or just click on this  [link]https://ideone.com/kd4Xw2

btw thanks a lot for your example "aba" and "acab" it really helps me out to gear up my code..